# Data between activities

Tags: java, android

I have a special class, a custom adapter for my `ListView` and I need to get some data from another Activity. But my implementation of the method `GetIntent()GetExtras()` isn't working. What is wrong?

Here is my custom adapter code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int myColor,myWidth;
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ColorTextButton);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HelpButton);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        String s = values[position];
        System.out.println(s);
        if (s.equals("Monday")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (s.equals("Wednesday")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
            textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (s.equals("Friday")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: use recyclerview instead listview at first. At second there is no intent between adapter and Activity as i know

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Cannot resolve method  getIntent()

Comment: you cant start a intent from a java class like from a activity. google that.

Comment: *A*, perhaps frowned upon, way to use data across multiple activities is to provide a singleton store. Another is to provide an on-device sqlite db.

Comment: "Another Activity", does that mean you want to have data from more than one Activity at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be accessable From a few activities you should think about use a singleton data Class. so in stead of trying to get pass the data from your adapter to a second activity both the adaper and the Activity use the same method to get the data class

```
 public class DataProvider {
 private static DataProvider instance;


    public static DataProvider getInstance()
    {
       if(null == instance){instance = new DataProvider();}
       return instnace;
    }

    public String[] getObjects(){
        return this.myStringArray;
    }

    // add more methods in here to retrieve and count your data as you need
 }
```

then in your Activity you can

```
// somewhere
myStingArrayInMyActivity = DataProvider.getInstance().getObjects()
```

also in you adapter
you can do

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
int myColor,myWidth;
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
  super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
  this.context = context;
  this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // your code
textView.setText(DataProvider.getInstance.getObjects[position]);

String s = DataProvider.getInstance.getObjects[position];
/// your code
 return rowView;
  }
 }
```

Comment: A few things: please format your code even if OP doesn't; it it's a list view with an adapter an ArrayList is probably more appropriate; and you're missing the array in the singleton.